# Pass url param to React.js root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to customize the style of my React.js app based on which client is using it, and I'm trying to pass the client id in the url. The url looks like this:

```
/#/app/client/dashboard
```

I created the `Rout` using this param:

```
<Route path="/app/:client/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Great. Now I want to retrieve the param in my root component. I tried two things. The first is to see if it's in the `props` object:

```
export default function App(props)
```

but it's not there.

Then I tried to set the `localStorage` with a client item in the `Dashboard` component, but that's too late because the `App()` function is called before the `Dashboard()` function.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There isn't a params `match` in props of Dashboard component?

Comment: if I get it straight you get the clientId in Dashboard component but you want to use it in the parent component? you want the parent component to also be able to read the query param

Comment: @naortor yes, exactly. I want it in the parent component.

Comment: @Irrech no, just `__proto__` and there's no `match` in it.

Comment: It **can only** be passed to a child component of the rendering `Route`. Where is `App` component in relation to `Dashboard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a right approach. If just the problem needs to be solved, give a try with window.location, as it will give access to the current url

```js
let url = window.location.pathname;
console.log(url);
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, the `pathname` is empty, but `window.location.href` has the information.